# Extjs4.1, Retrieve response message after store sync

Tags: extjs4.1

How to retrieve response message in failure function?

```
store.sync({
 success : function(){},
 failure : function(response, options){
   console.log(response.responseText); //it does not work, because there is responseText attr in response
 }  
});
```

Response Text is like this,

```
{"success":false,"message":"Test Error"}
```

Anybody know, please advice me.

Thanks

[EDIT]

```
console.log(response);
```

then,

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you get do `console.log( response )`? What would `console.log( response.message )` give? Are you sure the response text contains the object with success, or is it the result itself?

Comment: @Izhaki I added the console.log(response) result view into my question, could you review my question please? and there is no response.message.

Comment: Well, what you see is `Ext.data.batch`, thus no response. See my answer for solution.

Comment: Actually, could you change `response` to `batch` then try: console.log ( batch.operations[0].response.result );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you ever figured this out, but the suggestions above I'm pretty sure are wrong.  You need to look at the request exception of the store proxy.

Here is some code to call before you do the store sync.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options) {

  if (response.status != 200) {
    var errorData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    Ext.Msg.alert('Creating User Failed',errorData.message);
  }

});
```

Sorry for digging this old post up but it just hurt to see the answers above since I just went through the same struggle.

HTH's.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need:

```
store.sync({
    success: function(batch) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'Changes saved successfully.');
    },
    failure: function(batch) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Failed", batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The long and short of it all of these answers are incorrect or inefficient.

1. Ext.Ajax.on can be used, but you will have to worry about race conditions for requests. Do not use this solution because it can trap you easily. The Ext.Ajax.on might get fired for something other than the sync. See exhibit a.
2. batch.operations[0].response.responseText can be used too, but this is not reliable way of obtaining the response as the "response" object will not always be populated (It depends on the request and if there are exceptions, 404, 500, success: false, etc.)

**Exhibit a**

```
    // This picked up my autocomplete comboboxes load - not what I wanted!
    Ext.Ajax.on({
        requestcomplete: {
            fn: callback,
            scope: this,
            single: true
        },
        requestexecption: {
            fn: callback,
            scope: this,
            single: true
        }
    });
```

**Current solution**

*This still does not have the response I am looking for, but meh.*

```
    store.sync({
        failure: function (batch, eOpts) {
            // 'this' is the Ext.data.proxy.Ajax object
            // or whatever proxy you are using
            var data = this.getReader().jsonData,
                raw_data = this.getReader().rawData;
        }
    });
```

**I am not sure how this handles my full exception stack of cases, but I will amend my post based on the server-side exceptions I discover (404, 500, etc.)**